# Finding a number based on its divisors

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This is a question from a previous version of Belgian math championship for students. I'm trying to comprehend whether it has an answer that you can actually calculate, or not.

> Let $1 = d_1 < d_2 < d_3 <\cdots < d_k = n$ be all of the positive divisors of the positive integer $n$. Can one find the largest possible number $n$ such that
> $$n = d_2^2 + d_3^3?$$

One such example I find is $n=68$, with $d_2 = 2$, $d_3=4$.

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, but I feel like my limited knowledge in number theory is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Have you found any such $n$?  Can you, for example, say something abou $d_2$?

Comment: @lulu An example of an n could be 68 (d2 = 2, d3=4). d2 is just a divisor, bigger than 1 and smaller than n itself. What I'm looking for is the biggest possible n.

Comment: @jonas  Could $d_2$ be composite?  Could $d_2$ be odd?

Comment: @lulu yes and yes! Just a positive integer that is a divisor of n.

Comment: Please review the definition of $d_2$ and the connection between $d_2$ and $n$

Comment: Ask yourself:  could $6$ be the least proper divisor of a natural number $n$?  Could $9$?

Comment: Hint: the divisors of an odd number are all odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a hint (in a comment below the OP) into an answer, the divisors of an odd number are all odd, so $n$ cannot be odd, since in that case $d_2^2+d_3^3$ would be even. Thus $d_2=2$, hence $d_3^3=n-4$ implies $d_3$ is even as well. This implies $d_3=4$, so $n=2^2+4^3=68$ is the only example.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d_2=p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $n$. If $d_3=q$ is prime, then we have that $pq$ divides $n=p^2+q^3$, which is impossible (thanks to @Michale Barz's deleted partial answer). So $d_3$ must equal $p^2$. And now we have $n=d_1^2+d_3^3=p^2(1+p^4)$.

But if $p$ were odd, then $p^4+1$ would be even, which would force $d_2=2$, a contradiction.

Hence $p$ is an even prime.